Which Punisher live-action incarnation used an AT4 anti-tank weapon as referenced in "Deadpool & Wolverine"?
In Deadpool & Wolverine (2024), Deadpool mentions that there have been "like five" Punishers. This occurs during a scene where Gambit hands an AT4 anti-tank weapon to Blade, which Elektra identifies as belonging to the Punisher.


Deadpool: Where did you get that little beauty?
Elektra: That's Punisher's AT4.
Deadpool: Which Punisher? There's been like five of them.
Blade: There's only been one Blade. There's only ever gonna be one Blade.
Deadpool: [looks at camera]

Interestingly, Deadpool's look to the camera after Blade's statement seems to be a meta-joke poking fun at the fact that there isn't "ever gonna be one [Wesley Snipes] Blade," referring to the upcoming Blade film starring Mahershala Ali as Blade.
Over the years, there have been several live-action portrayals of the Punisher. These include Dolph Lundgren in The Punisher (1989), Thomas Jane in The Punisher (2004), Ray Stevenson in Punisher: War Zone (2008), and Jon Bernthal in Daredevil Season 2 (2016) and The Punisher (2017) series.
As someone only familiar with Bernthal's portrayal, I can't recall him ever using an AT4. This makes me wonder if any of the other live-action versions of the Punisher wielded such a weapon. Given the film's penchant for breaking the fourth wall and referencing live-action Marvel shows (most references in the film are to live-action Marvel shows), it's possible these lines are alluding to a particular live-action version of the Punisher. Or is Deadpool's comment simply a playful jab at the multiple actors who've taken on the role over the years?

I had a feeling the actor looked familiar. So that's Blade from my childhood.

Alas IMFD - says the M72 LAW was in a 2005 PS2 videogame and an unknown launcher was in 1993 arcade game, but no AT-4 turns up in any of the various Punisher appearances. I think it is a playful jab and no-one is expected to go and check, and most people wouldn't know the difference even if they saw one.

He uses a Stinger Missile in Circle of Blood (Vol. 2, Part 4).

https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Punisher/AT4_Owner_Punisher - only mention of it is in reference to the Nova conflict in Deadpool & Wolverine

RPG from the series? https://propstore.com/product/marvels-the-punisher/frank-castles-stunt-rocket-launcher-and-backpack/

but there is an AT-4 in https://www.eliotrbrown.com/wp/punisher-armory-1-page-3at4-light-antitank-weapon/ - The Punisher Armory No. 1, July, 1990

I think they're referring to a live-action Punisher version since most, if not all, references in the film are to live-action Marvel shows.

I thought so, but the only 'rocket launcher' reference in the movies, is, I think, Ray Stevenson's Punisher War Zone, and he clearly uses a Cobray CM79LF 37mm Launcher, which is used on a parkour bad guy, but the vfx effect is like a guided missile (?!) - and definitely not an AT-4.

IMFD reference in case its useful: https://www.imfdb.org/wiki/The_Punisher_(disambiguation)
